# Toast delayed until after drawing complete. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout

UPDATE 05/08/12 7:23AM:
I tried swapping the draw/toast, namely putting the Draw in the AsyncTask and the Toast in the main UI thread, but still no joy: no change in behavior.  I give up. But, thanks to all for suggestions.
-John

======================================

UPDATE 05/04/12 6:30PM:
I thought that the "single-task" issue might be the problem, and a worker thread might work, but since both threads by definition require access to the UI (main thread), it seemed to me like I'd still have contention.  Nonetheless, based on suggestion, I put the *toast* in an AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate(), but, as I feared, the problem persists.  (I didn't want to put the rendering in an async task because it's a monster and I was more comfortable putting the simple toast in the other task).  So, still no joy.  Any other suggestions on how to do this?

======================================

I've created an application that composes and draws a bitmap to the screen.  Because it takes 2-3 seconds to compose the bitmap, I want to show a Toast message to the user like "Refreshing, please standby...".  My problem is that the toast doesn't show up until *after* the paint is complete, even though I call Toast() *before* drawBitmap().

Ive seen behavior like this before, under Windows, because the message queue got backed up during a long computation,  The solution there was to periodically, explicitly dispatch messages during the long calculation.  But I can't figure out if/how to do this on Android.  Maybe the mysterious (to me) "Looper" ???

I've included a small, trivial app the isolates/demonstrates the problem.

Any suggestions *greatly* appreciated.
-John

```
//  PixmapTestMain.java

public class PixmapTestMain extends Activity {

public static View PixmapView;                  // pixmap view
public static Context Ctx;

// Create activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Ctx = this;
    PixmapView = findViewById( R.id.pixmap );
}

// Handle click
public void onClick(View v) {           // button view clicked
    PixmapView.invalidate();            // new pixmap
}

}  // end class PixmapTestMain
```

The custom view:

```
//  PixmapView - my custom view

public class PixmapView extends View {

static final int Wide=1000,High=1000,Size=(Wide*High);
static int toggle;

// Construct a view to display pixmap
public PixmapView(Context ctx,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctx, attrs);
}

// Handle onDraw callback
@Override
protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
    int[] pixmap;
    Bitmap bm;

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    toast( "Refreshing..." );
    pixmap = createPixmap();
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap( pixmap, Wide, High, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
    canvas.drawBitmap( bm, 0, 0, null );
}

// Create a pixmap
int[] createPixmap()
{
    int i,color;
    int[] pm;
    double s;
    Random rand = new Random();

    pm = new int[Size];                     // allocate pixmap

    toggle++;
    if( (toggle&1)==0 ) color = 0xff0000ff; // red
    else                color = 0xffff0000; // blue

    for( i=0; i<Size; i++ ) {
        pm[i] = color;
        rand.nextLong();        // slow me down
    }

    return( pm );
}

// Flash a toast message
public void toast( String msg)
{
    if( PixmapTestMain.Ctx == null ) return;
    Toast.makeText( PixmapTestMain.Ctx, msg, 0 ).show();
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
  android:text="Refresh"
  android:id="@+id/refresh"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:onClick="onClick"/>

<com.hyperdyne.PixmapTest.PixmapView
  android:id="@+id/pixmap"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your should move long-running tasks away from your UI thread, for example:

```
protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
    int[] pixmap;
    Bitmap bm;

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    toast( "Refreshing..." );
    pixmap = createPixmap();
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap( pixmap, Wide, High, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
    canvas.drawBitmap( bm, 0, 0, null );
}
```

should become:

```
private class DrawAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap[]> {
    int[] pixmap;
    Bitmap bm;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        pixmap = createPixmap();
        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap( pixmap, Wide, High, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
        return bm;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] result) {
        canvas.drawBitmap( result[0], 0, 0, null );
    }
}

protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    toast( "Refreshing..." );
    new DrawAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks lenik, i'll try that.  In my previous attempt, I left the drawing in the main UI task and spun off the toast.  I'll try the other way around as you suggest and post results.

Comment: There's no reason to put `Toast` in `AsyncTask` -- it does not require any significant time and works just fine on UI thread. The things you are supposed to put in `AsyncTask` are long-running tasks like file access, network access, complicated calculations or data processing.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the refresh for the canvas on the same thread as the Toast message. Since the redraw operation blocks the UI thread until it's complete, the toast message is unable to be rendered till the UI thread is unblocked. If you move the redraw operation into a worker thread, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both are sone on the UI with no delay between them, so you see the modification only after both end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I am loading a Google Map. The first time a Google Map is loaded, there is a significant delay due to the verification process of your api key as well as loading the initial map images. This can take on the order of several seconds and no toast will get displayed. A simple solution is to have the map load in either an AsyncTask or a separate Activity but **NOT** to launch the AsyncTask or Activity immediately but after a delay of 1 second. First you display your toast, then launch your process after a delay:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Handler handler = new Handler(); handler.postDelayed(DoSomething, 1000);

private Runnable DoSomething = new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      // Launch an AsyncTask here or some other activity to handle your long process.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
  }
};
```